# How to do this transformation using XSLT to identify whether node in XML has been deleted or re-created?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to have XSLT for the input below. The objective of this transformation is to identify whether a particular item has been ***deleted or re-created***.

Here is the input example:
**First Scenario:**

```
<root> 
    <nodeA id="a">
        <object id="1">
            <item1 id="xx" method="create">
                <attr>
                    <color>yellow</color>
                </attr>
            </item1>
        </object>
        <object id="1">
            <item1 id="xx" method="change">
                <any>blah</any>
                <attr>
                    <color>green</color>
                </attr>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="xx" method="delete" />                
        </object>  
        <object id="2">
            <item1 id="yy" method="create">
               <any>aaa</any>
            </item1>
        </object>
    </nodeA>            
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root> 
    <nodeA id="a">
        <object id="1">            
        </object>
        <object id="1">           
            <item1 id="xx" method="delete" />                
        </object>  
        <object id="2">
            <item1 id="yy" method="create">
               <any>aaa</any>
            </item1>
        </object>
    </nodeA>            
</root>
```

In the first scenario above we see that item1 has been created, changed and then deleted so that means it will be deleted in the end, that is why we only keep the `<item1 id="xx" method="delete" />` and disregards the other.

Second scenario:

```
<root> 
    <nodeB id="a">
        <object id="2">
            <item2 id="xx" method="create">
                <attr>
                    <color>yellow</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
        </object>
        <object id="2">
            <item2 id="xx" method="change">
                <attr>
                    <color>green</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
            <item2 id="xx" method="delete" /> <!-- because deletion occurs here, we disregard any previous node up until this delete -->
            <item2 id="xx" method="create"> <!-- we keep this node and any node afterwards -->
                <attr>
                    <color>pink</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
            <item2 id="xx" method="change">
                <any>blah</any>
                <attr>
                    <color>red</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
        </object>  
        <object id="3">
            <item2 id="yy" method="create">
                <any>ccc</any>
            </item2>
        </object>
    </nodeB>            
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root> 
    <nodeB id="a">
        <object id="2">            
        </object>
        <object id="2">            
            <item2 id="xx" method="create"> 
                <attr>
                    <color>pink</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
            <item2 id="xx" method="change">
                <any>blah</any>
                <attr>
                    <color>red</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
        </object>  
        <object id="3">
            <item2 id="yy" method="create">
                <any>ccc</any>
            </item2>
        </object>
    </nodeB>            
</root>
```

In the second scenario: we see that item2 after it is created and changed, it is deleted and then re-created and/or re-changed. That is why we disregard all the node up until the deletion and only keep all the node afterwards.

So in conclusion:

- create/change/.../delete -> will become delete
- create/change/.../delete/create2/change2/... -> create2/change2/...

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two rules to code in the XSLT

- If you have an item with a method of 'delete' then you only output it if there is no following item for the same @id (and parent @id)
- If you have an item with a method not of 'delete' then only output if if there no following 'delete' item for the same @id (and parent @id)

The first rule could be encoded like so

```
<xsl:if test="not(following::*
   [not(.//*[@id!=''])]
   [@id=current()/@id]
   [../@id = current()/../@id]
   [generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])">
```

And the second rule like so

```
 <xsl:if test="not(following::*
     [not(.//*[@id!=''])]
     [@method='delete']
     [@id=current()/@id]
     [../@id = current()/../@id]
     [generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])">
```

Note I am indentifying an 'item' node (i.e **item1** or **item2**) by looking for elements which don't have any child elements with @id attributes. Also note in both cases, I am assuming this only takes place within the current **nodeA/B** element.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='delete']">
        <xsl:if test="not(following::*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@id=current()/@id][../@id = current()/../@id][generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method!='delete']">
        <xsl:if test="not(following::*[not(.//*[@id!=''])][@method='delete'][@id=current()/@id][../@id = current()/../@id][generate-id(../..) = generate-id(current()/../..)])">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your first XML sample, the following is output

```
<root>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <object id="1"/>
        <object id="1">
            <item1 id="xx" method="delete"/>
        </object>
        <object id="2">
            <item1 id="yy" method="create">
                <any>aaa</any>
            </item1>
        </object>
    </nodeA>
</root>
```

When applied to your second XML sample (without comments), the following is output

```
<root>
    <nodeB id="a">
        <object id="2"/>
        <object id="2">
            <item2 id="xx" method="create">
                <attr>
                    <color>pink</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
            <item2 id="xx" method="change">
                <any>blah</any>
                <attr>
                    <color>red</color>
                </attr>
            </item2>
        </object>
        <object id="3">
            <item2 id="yy" method="create">
                <any>ccc</any>
            </item2>
        </object>
    </nodeB>
</root>
```